# Invoke Plupload Programmatically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, plupload

Is it possible that I could invoke [plupload](http://www.plupload.com) file upload dialog programmatically using any runtime?

Actually, I have a table with 9 cells. I want that when user clicks on a cell it calls upon a file upload dialog and upload an image in the same dialog.

Is it possible through Plupload?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke plupload programmatically client side, and even have several uploaders on your page.

A way to do it :

- having 9 invisible div containers with ids pludiv1, ... , pludiv9. They will contain your uploaders
- embed all your plupload initialization code in a pluploadInit function that takes an id as a parameter. In the function, you will use this id to retrieve the div and init the uploader inside it.
- upon click on buttonX, show pludivX first(important), and invoke pluploadInit with "pludivX" as a parameter.

As you will have several uploaders, pay attention to their contexts. For example, you will have to add some extra parameter to identify the button-uploader in your post request to the server.